# Returning a particular value instead of 0 in an unsuccessful search using std::find()

Tags: c++, std

I want to find a particular element in a list. If it was not found I want a particular value, say -1 to be returned. How to use std::find() for that?

I read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) that find() returns an iterator to the first element in the range [first,last) that compares equal to val. If no such element is found, the function returns last.

But that results in an ambiguous situation:

For example:

if the list is

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3

When I use

```
vector<int> v(4);
v.push_back(0);
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
vector<int>::iterator i;

i = find(v.begin(), v.end(), 4);
//Unsuccessful find, so I want a value, say -1.
cout<<*i<<endl;  //this prints zero during an unsuccessful search

i = find(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
cout<<*i<<endl;  //this too prints zero which is ambiguous
//because zero was already in my list
```

How to get rid of this ambiguous situation?

Comment: First try checking your returned iterator for `v.end()`, which is not deref-able to begin with, so to answer your finishing question, you get rid of the ambiguity by using the standard library *correctly*.

Comment: Well thanks, new with STL. but all the answers here were noteworthy. I was working on a problem of which this was a part. I was so much lost in the problem that couldn't think of this thing. So silly of me. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first call to `find` is returning the past-the-end iterator. You *cannot* dereference this iterator. You have undefined behaviour because you are doing so with `cout<<*i<<endl;`. The fact that it prints 0 is irrelevant.

It doesn't give an ambiguous situation, since it returns an copy of the second argument if it fails. In this case, it returns `v.end()`. You should be checking if the `std::find` was successful:

```
if (i != v.end()) {
  cout<<*i<<endl;
}
```

Comment: yes, but what happens if you do a find on a subrange of the collection, say `begin()` to `begin() + k` (with `k` smaller than the size of the collection)? Whether the returned iterator can be dereferenced or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @didierc Well then you need to compare to `begin() + k`. It's irrelevant that the code has undefined behaviour?

Comment: it's relevant for that particular instance of use of `find`, but not in the general case, which is what the question is aiming at.

Comment: @didierc I phrased it differently. How's that?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior. If the element is not found, `find` will yield a copy of the second iterator passed in, in this case `v.end()`. Dereferencing the `end()` iterator is undefined behavior.

You must test the iterator, not the value, to determine whether it was found:

```
if (i != v.end()) {
   std::cout << *i << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the last element of a range for `find` is not searched by the function, hence you can safely compare the returned iterator with it to know if the search was successful.

```
i = find(v.begin(), v.end(), 4);
//Unsuccessful find, so I want a value, say -1.
if (i != v.end())
   cout << *i << endl;
else
   cout << -1 << endl;
```

In your example, indeed the last element happens to be not dereferenceable, however you should follow the same principle if it were the case. Consider for example the situation were you want to search a subsequence of the collection: you would start by selecting the start and end entries of that collection which define the range, say `v.start()` and `v.start()+2`:

```
auto e = v.start()+2;
i = find( v.start(), e, 4);
if (i != e) 
    cout << *i << endl; // will output 4 if found
else
    cout << -1 << endl;
```

Here `e` is valid, yet it must be compared against to make sure that the result returned by `find` falls in the search range.

Comment: This is slightly misleading; the `last` element of the range is in fact an iterator to one past the end, and hence doesn't really exist...

Comment: @AlexChamberlain but _last_ could exist, as demonstrated by my second example, thank you for asking!